# ACF if statement not working when field is empty

Tags: php, if-statement, advanced-custom-fields

I have an ACF field for hero images called `hero_image`. This field sits at the top of my `single.php` page like so:

```
<?php
/**
 * The template for displaying all single posts
 *
 * @link https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/#single-post
 *
 * @package sitename
 */

get_header();
?>

<?php 
    $post_id = get_the_ID(); // Required as outside the loop
    $image = get_field('hero_image', $post_id);
    if ($image) {
        echo '<div class="hero">'.wp_get_attachment_image( $image, 'hero').'</div>';
    }
?>

<div class="has-sidebar">

    <div id="primary" class="content-area">

        <main id="main" class="site-main">

        <?php
        while ( have_posts() ) :
            the_post();

            get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', get_post_type() );

            the_post_navigation();

        endwhile; // End of the loop.
        ?>

        </main><!-- #main -->

    </div><!-- #primary -->

    <?php
        get_sidebar();
        get_footer();
    ?>

</div><!-- .has-sidebar -->
```

I'm using the `$post_id` variable to fetch the field from outside the loop. The image loads as expected.

If an image hasn't been uploaded for a post using the field, I'm expecting there to be no markup on the front-end. However, I still see the following:

```
<div class="hero"></div>
```

Why isn't my if statement working when the field isn't in use?

Comment: Have you checked what comments_open() is sending or get_comments_number() is sending...?? If either of the one is true... Your if will work ... Because you have used OR

Comment: Comments are switched off, so I shouldn't imagine it's sending anything. I've commented this out and the results remain the same.

Comment: Try if(trim($image)!= Null) instead of if($image)

Comment: What does $image sends if image has not been uploaded?

Comment: Both `if(trim($image)!= Null)` and `if($image)` still output `<div class="hero"></div>` if an image hasn't been uploaded.

Comment: No I am saying print the $image before the if condition and check what is printing?

Comment: If I print or echo the `$image` variable before the if statement, I get an integer (791).

Comment: Then you should check your code... If $image is not empty it will surely show the markup

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did some further digging and found my problem.

I have two ACF fields `hero_image` and `thumbnail_image`. These are set to appear on all pages and posts including custom post types.

Looking at the `header.php` file, here's what I found:

```
<?php
    // Get post ID
    $post_id = get_queried_object_id();
    // Hero image
    $hero = get_field('hero_image', $post_id);
    $hero_url = wp_get_attachment_url( get_field('hero_image', $post_id), 'hero');
?>

<?php if ( is_single() || is_archive() ): ?>
    <header id="masthead" class="site-header">
<?php else: ?>
    <header id="masthead" <?php if ($hero) { echo 'class="site-header has-background" style="background:url('.$hero_url.')"'; } else { echo 'class="site-header"'; } ?>>
<?php endif; ?>
```

As you can see, I'm also using the variable `$post_id` outside the loop. This prevented the second `$post_id` variable working via `single.php`.

I’ve renamed `$post_id` in header.php to `$post_id_outside_loop`. I’ve then used this variable via `single.php` as it’s also outside the loop. This has solved the issue.

```
<?php
/**
 * The template for displaying all single posts
 *
 * @link https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/#single-post
 *
 * @package sitename
 */

get_header();
?>

<?php 
    // $post_id_outside_loop is set via header.php
    $image = get_field('hero_image', $post_id_outside_loop);
    if ($image) {
        echo '<div class="hero">'.wp_get_attachment_image( $post_id_outside_loop, 'hero').'</div>';
    }
?>

<div class="has-sidebar">

    <div id="primary" class="content-area">

        <main id="main" class="site-main">

        <?php
        while ( have_posts() ) :
            the_post();

            get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', get_post_type() );

            the_post_navigation();

            // If comments are open or we have at least one comment, load up the comment template.
            if ( comments_open() || get_comments_number() ) :
                comments_template();
            endif;

        endwhile; // End of the loop.
        ?>

        </main><!-- #main -->

    </div><!-- #primary -->

    <?php
        get_sidebar();
        get_footer();
    ?>

</div><!-- .has-sidebar -->
```